# query.first object always be undefined

Tags: javascript, object, parse-platform

I have a table name country,I key in a country name to find which one is correspond,but my logs shows {object,object} and keep render the message
"Failed".
Please give me some advice.

```
  var redeemnum = req.body.redeemnum;
  var country = Parse.Object.extend("country");  
  var query = new Parse.Query(country); 
  query.equalTo("name", redeemnum);
  query.first({  
   success: function(object) {
       if (typeof object === 'undefined') {
           res.render("wrong", { msg : "Failed!" } );
       } 
       else { 
            res.render("wrong", { msg : "Got it!" } );
           }
       }
  })
```

Comment: {object, object} might be the result you want.  try logging `JSON.stringify(result)`

Comment: But when I try to get some value like *object.get("number")*,it can't get the result,so [object,object]is not the answer I want.

Comment: I see.  I didn't notice that you said "Failed" was being rendered, too.  So `{object, object}` must be an error.  Do you suppose the error message might contain a valuable hint?

Comment: What is valuable hint you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be old but I just ran into this and just checked if the object returned == null .. so with your code here is what It might look like..

```
  var redeemnum = req.body.redeemnum;
  var country = Parse.Object.extend("country");  
  var query = new Parse.Query(country); 
  query.equalTo("name", redeemnum);
  query.first({  
   success: function(object) {
       if (object == null) {
           res.render("wrong", { msg : "Failed!" } );
       } else { 
            res.render("wrong", { msg : "Got it!" } );
       }
     }
  })
```